# How to make Angular parent FormGroup invalid until all nested FormGroups are valid

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive, angular-forms, angular-validation

I have a FormGroup containing nested FormGroups. I want to put a validator on the BasicInfo child FormGroup (on FirstName control) using the code below. However, I want to disable the submit button if the entire parent form group is invalid. If any of the children are invalid, it should be invalid until all children are valid. But this is not happening on initial load. It only happens if I touch any of the child input elements.

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/user-registration-with-fgd-pxafnk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser-registration%2Fuser-registration%2Fuser-registration.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fuser-registration%2Fuser-registration%2Fuser-registration.component.ts)

user-registration.component.ts (parent component). First name should be required

```
 .....
  this.userForm = this.fb.group({
  basicInfo: this.fb.group({
    firstName: [],
    lastName: [],
    email: [],
    age: []
  }),
  .....
```

basic-info.component.ts

```
  //setting required firstName
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.form.get('firstName').setValidators(Validators.required)
    this.form.updateValueAndValidity()
  }
```

basic-info.component.html
[image]

Parent form always returns true on initial load. The submit button should be disabled if the firstName is blank.
[image: Parent form always returns true on initial load]

Comment: basicInfo: this.fb.group({
    firstName: [null, Validators.required],
    lastName: [null, Validators.required],...ect

Comment: Yes, but I want to set the validations inside of the basic info using `setValidators()`. I don't want to set them on the parent form

Answer (score -1):

this.form.controls["firstName"].addValidators([Validators.required]);